# Why Math.Floor(4) somehow equals 3 in C#?

Tags: c#, math, double

I am doing some math with doubles in C#. There's a piece of my code:

```
for(int i = 0 ;; i++){
        double step = num / Math.Pow(10,i + 1);
        step = step - Math.Floor(step);
        step = step * 10;
        Console.WriteLine(step + " " + Math.Floor(step));
        ...
}
```

So, I get that problem when `num` equals 14. In the first iteration (`i` equals 0) `Console.WriteLine` gives an output `4 3`, which means `Math.Floor(4)` returned 3. Is it some double type problem or what?

Comment: Recognise that 1/10 (0.1) can't be expressed exactly in binary, in the same way that 1/3 (0.3 recurring) can't be expressed exactly in decimal. 14 / 10 = 1.4, which has a fractional value of 0110011001100110011 (and so on) in binary.

Comment: please, inspect `Console.WriteLine(step.ToString("R"));` - `double` without any rounding; you may want to look at fractional part: `step % 1`

Comment: Since you're doing arithmetic in base 10, consider using the `decimal` type instead, since they're better suited to base 10 numbers.